# Automatic double-click sort columns using VBA with empty columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I found this code to help me to sort some Excel sheets.

```
Public blnToggle As Boolean
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick _
    (ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim LastColumn As Long, keyColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim SortRange As Range
    LastColumn = _
    Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    keyColumn = Target.Column
    
    If keyColumn > LastColumn Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cancel = True
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, keyColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SortRange = Target.CurrentRegion
    blnToggle = Not blnToggle
    If blnToggle = True Then
    SortRange.Sort _
    Key1:=Cells(2, keyColumn), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Else
    SortRange.Sort _
    Key1:=Cells(2, keyColumn), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End If
    Set SortRange = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub
```

It works, but i have many headers. Wanted it starts sorting in the third cell (where is the header i want to be sorted) instead the first one, so i changed `A1` to `A3`. But when i double click, nothing happens.

Also i have some empty columns next the columns with value, and the code not recognize these empty columns and sort wrong.

Someone can help me to make it sort the value columns also sorting the next empty colmuns starting by the header in the third cell below?

---

Edit 1:

[image]

This is an example of my sheet. There's some empty columns between some valued columns. For example, if i double click on `Item 4` all columns have to be sorted together and it is not hapanning because theres some empty columns.
Another point i forgot to say: The last row can't be sorted because is the total of the itens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Public blnToggle As Boolean
    
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Const NUM_HEADER_ROWS As Long = 3
    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, keyColumn As Long
    Dim SortRange As Range
    
    LastColumn = Me.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    
    LastRow = Me.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    keyColumn = Target.Column
    If keyColumn > LastColumn Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Row <> NUM_HEADER_ROWS Then Exit Sub 'Edit: exit if header was not clicked
    
    Cancel = True
    
    'sort range includes last header row, and excludes totals row
    Set SortRange = Me.Cells(NUM_HEADER_ROWS, 1).Resize(LastRow - NUM_HEADER_ROWS, LastColumn)
     
    SortRange.Sort Key1:=Me.Cells(NUM_HEADER_ROWS + 1, keyColumn), _
         Order1:=IIf(blnToggle, xlAscending, xlDescending), Header:=xlYes
    
    blnToggle = Not blnToggle
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Good! But it's not sorting the rest of the columns, because between valued columns has some empty columns, ant the entire sheet isn't be sorted by these empty columns.

Comment: Those empty columns don't even have headers?  If that's the case then you can't use `CurrentRegion` and you'll need to use `LastColumn` and a similar `LastRow` to define the bottom-right corner of the sort range. See update above

Comment: Please check my `Edit 1`. I tried to explain better.

Comment: OK would have saved a lot of time if you'd posted that screen shot in your initial question...   Try the edit above.

Comment: Work like a charm! Nice job! I just have to ask you if has a way to make it sort only if i press some cell of the third row (`ITEM 1, ITEM 2, ITEM 3...`. Actually if i double click anywhere of some value it alsos sort. If is easy to fix it i really would aprreciate. Anyway you did a great job and i'm greatfull! :-]

Comment: See edit above for how to exit if the last header row was not clicked.

Comment: Good! Thank you!